# Is there any way to fetch song's genre using MediaStore?

Tags: android, mediastore, mediametadataretriever

Using this method of audio file retrieval from Android's external storage

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
```

can I actually find a resonable way to fetch a genre of the given song? MediaStore class seems to provide everything else - from song's title to its composer info - except for the genre field. Should I use MediaMetadataRetriever then? If so, how drastically can creating a MediaMetadataRetriever instance for every song on a device reduce app's performance?

Maybe there are some better ways to retrieve all audio files from both external and internal storages in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned at [Developer's Site](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.Genres.html),

You can fetch the Genres of the Audio file using **MediaStore.Audio.Genres**

Sample Code :

```
private static String[] genresProj = {
            MediaStore.Audio.Genres.NAME,
            MediaStore.Audio.Genres._ID
    };

 int idIndex = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);

 while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                int id = Integer.parseInt(mediaCursor.getString(idIndex));

                Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.getContentUriForAudioId("external", id );
                genresCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri,
                        genresProj , null, null, null);
                int genreIndex = genresCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Genres.NAME);                


                    while (genresCursor.moveToNext()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Genre = " +genresCursor.getString(genreIndex));
                    }

            }
        }
```

To fetch other details of the Audio file, please check [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.html) .